# "No A or B" vs. "Neither A nor B"

Tags: expressions

I wrote "No error or issue since 2013".
I feel this is natural when I say so. But, in written English, because of the first "No", I wonder the "or" should be changed to "nor". Or, maybe "Neither error nor issue since 2013" will be better. What is better?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your feeling that it's "natural" is incorrect. Using the singular in this way *(error/issue)* is extremely ***unnatural*** in the context of idiomatic speech patterns. It's almost exclusively a feature of geeky computer documentation, officialese, etc.

Comment: @FumbleFingers What would be the best when people say the same content? "No errors or issues since 2013" ?

Comment: @ Daebarkee: In your specific case I've no hesitation in saying plural *"No errors or issues since 2013"* is the form native speakers would always use. But I'm not 100% sure *why* this is, so [I've asked a question myself](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/149590/singular-plural-in-no-x-since-vs-no-xs-since)

Comment: @FumbleFingers Thank you for quick update. it seems that plural expressions are much common than singular (noun) expressions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Neither sentence really makes sense.  If you wanted to use nor I would suggest the following:

> There has been neither an error nor an issue since 2013

Comment: This sounds stilted, though; hardly anyone uses "nor" outside of literature.  I would say, "There have been no errors or issues since 2013."

Answer (score 0):

Neither ... nor... pair is used as adverb/pronoun in a complete sentence. so your expression "Neither error nor issue since 2013" is only part of a sentence, you may say neither error nor issue have been found since 2013. whereas No error or issue since 2013 is informal way of saying there have not been error or issue since 2013 hope it helps